# Alter System Flush Shared_Pool

Tags: oracle11g

We have an application that uses Oracle 11 forms and Oracle 11 DB. Every now and then the application runs slow and I have to run ALTER SYSTEM FLUSH SHARED_POOL in order to speed it up. The company that supports the application has been unable to find a long term solution for me. Any ideas as to what might be the cause? What might be the remedy?

Comment: The remedy is to fix the respective application. Most probably it doesn't use bind variables, which is causing a lot of additional library cache load. Tracing a sql session will easily reveal that.

Answer (score 2):

There are many definetly no-questions for oracle db. Two of them:

1. Is there any undocumented `_FAST=TRUE` parameter? NO!
2. Is flushing shared pool a solution? [NO!](http://www.dbasupport.com/forums/showthread.php?19834-Significance-impact-of-ALTER-SYSTEM-FLUSH-SHARED_POOL!)

It is hard to tell without knowing what, on what configuration, with what upload etc. is going on. Diagnosis can't be done by photo. But from my past experience, the most common root of evil is running application.

First question must be "Does my application use [bind variables](http://www.rittmanmead.com/2004/03/bind-variables-explained/)?". Then start to evaluate you shared pool size, [monitor performance](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10822/toc.htm) etc. What queries spool shared pool, why they plans become ineffective? Do you gather statistics? And so on.